# Android: How do I get the Application Context as an Activity from a class that extends Application?

Tags: java, android

How do I retrieve the **Application Context as an Activity** in class that extends Application? I need to retrieve the context as an Activity so that I can broadcast `PendingIntent`s. My current code is:

```
public class SharedResources extends Application {
    private static Activity context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        context = (Activity) getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

But I get an error, stating that my class `SharedResources` cannot be cast to `android.app.Activity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need activity context for shared preferences. You can get the shared preferences instance in the following manner also.

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("YOUR_SHARED_PREF_NAME", 0)
```

SharedPreferences just needs a context object, not activity context.

Comment: I also need to broadcast PendingIntents, which require an Activity context.

Comment: So then the question is wrong. Check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#getActivity(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)